# Markov-Switching model of distribution

Tags: distributions, markov-process

I was wondering if anyone knows of any work concerning markov-switching models and more precisely that changes the distribution of the error terms? I've found some literature for conditional mean, variance, and degrees of freedom but i can't find anything for different distributions.

thanks.